# How to remove elements from array which are exist in second array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

```
const arr1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
const arr2 = ["b", "d"];
```

I need to do something which remove "b" and "d" from arr1. Of course I need to remove elements from arr1 which exist in arr2 too.

Comment: what do you mean with *"remove"*? keep the same array without common items?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) + [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const arr1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
const arr2 = ["b", "d"];

let result = arr1.filter(el => !arr2.includes(el));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yup it's woring, but give me some time I need to test it in my code case :D